# Is it possible to display respective country flag to out side of the select function. Or Can we display country flag on the both place

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

```js
 function onChangeCallback(ctr) {
            console.log("The country was changed: " + ctr);
            //$("#selectionSpan").text(ctr);
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".niceCountryInputSelector").each(function(i, e) {
                new NiceCountryInput(e).init();
            });
        });
```

```css
.container {
    
    margin: 80px auto !important;
    padding: 15px;
    
}
.bg-box1 {
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    padding: 30px;
/*    width: 460px;*/
    width: 700px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #808080;
    border-radius: 6px;
    
}
.bg-box {
    
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #484848;
    border-radius: 6px;

 
}
select {
        border-radius: 6px;
}
.search {
    src: url(img/search.png);
}
.niceCountryInputMenu {
    background: white !important;
    color: black !important;
    border: 1px solid #a8a8a8;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #808080
     /*
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    */
}
.niceCountryInputMenuDefaultText {
    width: 270px;
    padding: 6px;
    margin: 6px 0px 0px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    
    
    
}
.niceCountryInputMenuDefaultText a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    
}
.niceCountryInputMenu a {
    color: #787878 !important;
}
.niceCountryInputMenuDropdown {
    /*border-left: 1px solid #a8a8a8;*/
    height: 30px;
    width: 25px;
    float: right;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    color: #484848;
    
}
.niceCountryInputMenuDropdownContent {
    border: 1px solid #a8a8a8;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    border-top: 0;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.niceCountryInputMenuDropdownContent a {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    color: #787878 !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #F5F5F5;
  
 
    /*
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    */
}
.niceCountryInputMenuDropdownContent a:hover {
    background-color: #63a2d7 !important;
    color: white !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    
    
}
.niceCountryInputMenuFilter {
    border: 1px solid #a8a8a8;

    border-top: -10;
    border-bottom: 0;
    
}
.niceCountryInputMenuFilter input {
    width: 100%;
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    color: #808080;
    
   
}
.niceCountryInputMenuCountryFlag {
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    width: 23px;
    height: 18px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.niceCountryInputMenuCountryNoFlag {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    line-height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 22px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://manishasecurity.in/creative-js/niceCountryInput.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">


        <h3>Select a Country:</h3>
        <div class="bg-box1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">

                    <div style="background-color: #fff; width: 160px; height: 50px;margin-top: 0px; padding: 4px; border-radius: 6px;font-size: 12px;" data-showflags="true" class=""></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="niceCountryInputSelector bg-box" style="width: 400px;" data-selectedcountry="ad" data-showspecial="false" data-showflags="true" data-i18nall="All selected" data-i18nnofilter="No selection" data-i18nfilter="Search Country..." data-onchangecallback="onChangeCallback" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Hi,
I have made the country flag dropdown list.

In the dropdown list, whether it is scroll by mouse or search country name in the search box, the country will be autocompleted and it will be displayed in the input field with the country name and flag.

The dropdown function working properly.

**Requirement:-**
Without removing its Name and flag from the dropdown section, Can we display Country Flag outside of the dropdown section?. I am trying for that but I am not able to do that.

I hope someone can understand and help me out in this situation.

Thanks Lots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the function `onChangeCallback` to place the flag to the other div.

```
    function onChangeCallback(ctr) {
            let flag=$(".niceCountryInputSelector").find("[data-flagiso='"+ctr+"']")[0];
            flag=$(flag).clone();
            $(".col-4").children("div:first-child").empty();
            $(".col-4").children("div:first-child").append(flag);
        }
```

So, you can append the `flagObjElement` to where you want to append.

Comment: I try might be I am doing the wrong way can you edit the code and display the flag on the other div.

Comment: My Code is Updated.

Comment: The keyboard arrow key is not working how can I add the script on this for keyboard up and down

Comment: also, can I increase the flag image size of the flag which is displaying in col-4

Comment: how can hide the flag icon from the dropdown

Comment: Yes, just remove the flag=$(flag).clone(); statement.

Comment: You can use `$(flag).width("50px");` and `$(flag).height("50px");` to the image size.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236127/discussion-between-user3181077-and-the-knvb).